# return Array[] or return null Java

Tags: java

This is a method I'm working on.  It needs to return an Array[] of results or return null.
However, I'm getting a NullPointerException error when I attempt to test it.  I've been searching and getting nowhere the past few hours.  Any help for a suffering student would be appreciated.

```
public Item[] searchByName(String name) {

    String n = name;
    ArrayList<Item> sortName = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item[] matchArr;
    boolean noResult = false;

    for(int j = 0; j < itemInventory.size(); j++){
        if(itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) == true)
            sortName.add(itemInventory.get(j));
        else
            noResult = true;
    }
    matchArr = new Item[sortName.size()];
    for(int j = 0; j < sortName.size(); j++){
        matchArr[j] = sortName.get(j);
    }
    if(noResult == true)
        return null;

    else
        return matchArr;

}
```

//Revised version
//itemInventory is an ArrayList of objects being inventoried and sorted.

```
public Item[] searchByName(String name) {

    String n = name;
    ArrayList<Item> sortName = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item[] matchName;

    for(int j = 0; j < itemInventory.size() ; j++){
        if(itemInventory.get(j) != null){
            if(itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) == true){
                sortName.add(itemInventory.get(j));
                System.out.println(j + " Is a match");
            }
        }               
    }

    if(sortName.size() == 0)
        return null;
    else{
        matchName = sortName.toArray(new Item[sortName.size()]);
        return matchName;
    }
```

Comment: You have not even specified which line causes NPE

Comment: Can u pls post the error stack trace?

Comment: Sounds like you're ready to learn one of the most important skills that you can learn as a Java programmer: how to debug a _NullPointerException_.  Your stack trace should tell you _EXACTLY_ which line caused the Exception.  Once you know that, you need to look at every variable that is de-referenced on that line (ie has a method called on it) and check if it is null.  You will do this thousands of times if you decide to write Java code for a living.

Comment: post the error log or console

Comment: I guess that this line `itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) == true` causes NPE. Make sure that `itemInventory.get(j)` is not `null` before you get the name.

Comment: What is itemInventory? Maybe that's where you're getting a null pointer exception. Could you tell us what line gives you a null pointer exception?

Comment: @electr0hed: check your stacktrace.. go to the last lines of it.. The follwing link helps [stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun.  That was it!! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this line `itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) == true` causes NPE. Make sure that `itemInventory.get(j)` is not `null` before you get the name:

```
if(itemInventory.get(j)!=null) //only then get the name
    if(itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n))
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something in front of my face.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped :) Next time, try to debug it, that  will help you a lot. Debugging your code will help you to understand what's the problem and why it is happening, specially when it comes to `NullPointerException`

Comment: @MarounMaroun : `equalsIgnoreCase(n)` already returns true or false, you do not have to check it again. You could directly use `if(itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n))`.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale If `itemInventoy.get(j)` is null, then you are getting a name of a `null` object (`null.getName()`), which will cause a `NullPointerException`. So you have to check weather it is `null` before you get the name. (The exception is thrown before you get to `equalsIgnoreCase(n)`)

Comment: @MarounMaroun : I am talking about 2nd if in your code. `if(itemInventory.get(j).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(n) == true)`.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Sorry I misunderstood you. Yes I know, I just didn't want to change his original line (I copy pasted it). Thanks for clarifying this :)